# Use SimpleXML to parse multiple RSS feeds

Tags: php, rss, simplexml

How can I put multiple RSS feeds from SimpleXML into an array sorted by pubDate?

Example:

```
feed[0] = 'http://www.example.org/feed1.rss';
feed[1] = 'http://www.thing.org/feed.rss';
...
feed[n] = '..';

#Fetch feeds
#Sort by pubDate

foreach ($feeds as $row) {
   //Do something
   print '<item>
          <title>...</title>
          </item>';
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// Set the feed URLs here
$feeds = array(
    'http://www.example.org/feed1.rss',
    'http://www.example.org/feed2.rss',
    // etc.
);

// Get all feed entries
$entries = array();
foreach ($feeds as $feed) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
    $entries = array_merge($entries, $xml->xpath('/rss//item'));
}

// Sort feed entries by pubDate (ascending)
usort($entries, function ($x, $y) {
    return strtotime($x->pubDate) - strtotime($y->pubDate);
});

print_r($entries);
```

Works in PHP 5.3.

Comment: Hello, I print the entries but the sorting it doesn't work... ( in my case)

Answer (score 0):

You put the item values into a multi-dimensional array, then sort using usort(), then print. Do you have more specific questions?

Comment: That seems like I have to do an extra loop.  Is there any built-in way to fetch multiple feeds at once?

Comment: Grab each feed, and use merge_array()